# Displaying a form within another form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, awesomium

I am building a web browser application using c# and the awesomium web framework . I have a form containing a dock panel within which I would like to display another form that holds the awesomium web-control . Basically the parent form facilitates creating tabs and the one with the webControl has the browsing engine and is rendered within the tabs .

Is this possible ? If yes , can you give me some tips on how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed a form in another control if set `TopLevel = false;`

```
private void EmbedForm()
{
    Form f = new Form();
    f.TopLevel = false;
    f.BackColor = Color.White;
    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    f.Visible = true;
    panel1.Controls.Add(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move common UI content to **UserControl** and use it in a both form.
It is a most common practice.